# Complete expressiveness for language using only the implication connective and propositional constant

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Show that we can obtain complete expressiveness for a language using only the implication connective if we add to our language the “propositional constant” ⊥ which always has the truth value 0 (false).

I found this problem in *Introduction to Logic* by Paul Herrick. I'm really stumped on how to prove this.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Negation and disjunction are known to be logically complete, so if we can express them in terms of implication and falseness, we are all set.

$$\neg P=P\to\bot$$
$$P\vee Q=(P\to\bot)\to Q$$
and, just to see how to keep building these: 
$$P\wedge Q=(P\to(Q\to\bot))\to\bot$$
$$P\equiv Q=((P\to Q)\to((Q\to P)\to\bot))\to\bot$$